# jsf Converter: How to find out the class type of the actual passed value String?

Tags: java, jsf, generics

I'm trying to bind custom class objects together with MyFaces UI-components like checkboxes/combos, etc. but without giving the explicit type like int/float/boolean/String/List<String> by creating the getters/setters in the backing bean.

So in my case it will usually look like this:

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="mylist" value="#{bean.myListValueHolder.data}"
    converter="myValueConverter">
    ...
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

Where:

- bean is backing bean
- myListValueHolder is of type MyValueHolder<T>
- data is of type <T>

I'm trying to use a custom Converter for it and this class signature:

```
public class MyValueHolder<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<T> {
....
```

MyValueHolder has this methods:

```
public T getData() {
...
public void setData(Object data) {
...
public void setData(T data) {
...
```

My Converter:

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent c, String value) {
...
```

**The problem**: how can I find out the type **<T>** passed as **value** at the runtime? It can be a boolean, int, float, double, String, or List<String> in my case.

But I kinda dislike to write

1. A lot of "try to cast to a type and if it succeeds, its your type" but without knowing for sure, whether its a int or a float/double.
2. Giving the type as a parameter or as second parameter as I define my h:selectOneListbox
3. ???

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** OK, List would not work. But the question is, is it any good to bind values from JSF UIComponents in my view to some kind of a value wrapper to avoid write to many simple "dummy" getters/setters in my backing beans?

So I could use "one" bean which will have the MyValueHolder accessible by Key (property name which is a String) like "bean.get('property_name')" or over "#{bean.myListValueHolder.data}" or similar syntax?

**EDIT2:** To answer BalusC question and to explain the Why.

As for now, I'm not sure whether this approach is a good one.

My data comes as XML, I parse it to save it as `key`, `value` pairs. My UI-elements have also a particular `state`(s) (EnumSet from a `State`-Enum {hidden, visible, disabled, enabled, hover, focus, active, ...} which is dependent from specific values stored in `ValueHolders`. The dependency of required `State`(s) is described in a `Rule` class, which has an `EnumSet` of `State` and a `matches` method, which returns `true` if the defined `State` shall be applied because the `Rule` matches. Then I have a `ValueChangedListeners` which shall apply new `State`(s) to the UI-Components if the `Value` has been changed and the `Rules` associated with that `Value` match.

At least this is how I thought, I can do this. So I can query for value and ui-state from my view and if some concrete value changes, which in turn might change the `State` of the `UIComponent` I can invoke a callback and depending on the new `State` add/remove a new css class to that particular component via JQuery.

Well, sounds kinda complex or pretty overkill, but I want to define my UI-Component `States` in Java, so I can change the `State` from Java too and not having the State-Rules defined in the view.

Comment: With type erasure involved?  I'm not sure you can.

Comment: @LouisWasserman actually I don't care about the HOW as long as it works (even if I need to parse the content of the passed String) or if someone points out that what I'm trying to do is totally wrong..

Comment: `List` doesn't implement `Comparable`. So that would in first place already not work for `List`. What do you really have now? This question is however answerable for types which really implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @BalusC as being said, int/float/double/boolean/String and he case List<>. I mean if that's not doable, any idea how to accomplish similar approach?

Comment: How did you get your code to compile when using `List` as `T` in first place?

Comment: @BalusC uh, thats a good question, I'm not doing it, just planned to include List<String> too, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JSF `Converter` is not suitable for this. You need a custom [`ELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) for this. Extending [`BeanELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/BeanELResolver.html) and overriding `getType()`, `getValue()` and `setValue()` wherein you grab the concrete `ValueHolder` implementation should do it. This way you can ultimately end up with expressions like `value="#{bean.myStringValueHolder}"` without the `.data`. This way the data coercion/conversion will then automatically be done by JSF/EL.

You can register the custom EL resolver on application's startup by `Application#addELResolver()`:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().addELResolver(new ValueHolderELResolver());
```

As to figuring the generic type, assuming that `ValueHolder` is an `abstract class` and you've concrete implementations like `StringValueHolder extends ValueHolder<String>` and so forth, then you'll be able to extract the generic type in the constructor of `ValueHolder`.

```
public abstract class ValueHolder<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<T> {

    private Class<T> type;
    private T data;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ValueHolder() {
        this.type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = type.cast(data);
    }

}
```

I only wonder how this entire approach is useful. There's some seemingly unnecessary overhead. What exactly is the functional requirement? It is just eliminating getter/setter boilerplate? Why not just using model objects (javabeans/entities/etc) so that you end up with only one model property in the backing bean? Is it being tired of typing them everytime? A bit decent IDE can autogenerate them. Even more, complete javabean classes can be autogenerated based on a list of property names and a few clicks.

Comment: Is the XML style definition static or dynamic?

Comment: You could use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) to map between a XML file and a fullworthy Javabean.

Comment: I'm using JAXB to unmarshal XML-content, which generates "dummy" Object-classes by given XSD. I'm then putting it into a Map<Property_Name, Value> to ease access via SomeClass.getProperty('name'). I'm new to J2EE stuff, so don't know how to create Javabeans with JAXB by given XML (googling didn't answered it).

Comment: Click the JAXB link in my previous comment :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10892/discussion-between-lzdt-and-balusc)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a instance of your converter to your bean and bind it to your input element, then you know the type. This way you could also pass the objects to convert to the converter via a constructor and perform simple lookup. Not that handsome but it would work.